# jssor slider missing picture in IE but ok in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jssor, jquery-ui-slider

When I use Google Chrome it works fine. But not in IE11. In IE11, the img/thumb-01.jpg comes up but NOT the img/01.jpg. The transition, arrow all is fine.

I have tried  replacing it with  and it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;">

    <!-- The following codes demostrate jssor slider work with jquery library -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider-20.mini.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider-20.debug.js instead for debug -->
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,

$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease

$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
              {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
            ];

            var jssor_1_options = {
              $AutoPlay: true,
              $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1
              },
              $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
              },
              $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                $Cols: 10,
                $SpacingX: 8,
                $SpacingY: 8,
                $Align: 360
              }
            };

            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 800);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>

    <style>

        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
        /*
        .jssora05l                  (normal)
        .jssora05r                  (normal)
        .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
        .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url('img/a17.png') no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
        .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
        .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
        .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
        .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
        .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

        /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
        /*
        .jssort01 .p            (normal)
        .jssort01 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
        .jssort01 .p.pav        (active)
        .jssort01 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
        */
        .jssort01 .p {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 72px;
            height: 72px;
        }

        .jssort01 .t {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }

        .jssort01 .w {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .jssort01 .c {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 68px;
            height: 68px;
            border: #000 2px solid;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            background: url('img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
            _background: none;
        }

        .jssort01 .pav .c {
            top: 2px;
            _top: 0px;
            left: 2px;
            _left: 0px;
            width: 68px;
            height: 68px;
            border: #000 0px solid;
            _border: #fff 2px solid;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }

        .jssort01 .p:hover .c {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            border: #fff 1px solid;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }

        .jssort01 .p.pdn .c {
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            width: 68px;
            height: 68px;
            border: #000 2px solid;
        }

        * html .jssort01 .c, * html .jssort01 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01 .pav .c {
            /* ie quirks mode adjust */
            width /**/: 72px;
            height /**/: 72px;
        }

    </style>


    <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 456px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-

color: #24262e;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/01.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-01.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-02.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/03.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-03.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/04.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-04.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/05.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-05.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/06.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-06.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/07.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-07.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/08.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-08.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/09.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-09.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/10.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-10.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/11.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-11.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/12.jpg" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-12.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
        <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:800px;height:100px;" data-autocenter="1">
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
            <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
                <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                    <div class="w">
                        <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
        <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:158px;left:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:158px;right:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
        <a href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Jssor Slider</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the original image slider from JSSOR. All I did was put in my picture of choice and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to IE11 Developer Tools.

I got the following error in the debugging section "Images failing to load in IE with DOM: 7009 error (unable to decode)".

All I had to do was to rename the .jpg into .png and it worked fine in IE11. Tried .svg, .gif and it did not work. The jssor image slider is working fine now.